# How to make 2 surfaces parallel to each other

Tags: normals

I want the surface of plane A to be parallel to the surface of plane B (I know it's a curvature). How do I make a surface parallel to any random angle? Please guide. (photo attached).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *Edit* mode, select the face of Object B, in the *Transform Orientations* panel, click on the "+" button to create a custom orientation, keep this new orientation selected, back to *Object* mode, select your Object A, go in the header menu > *Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation*.